# Cannot extend my custom component's validation rules -- does not validate

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, form, validation, class-extensions

I'm following along with this tutorial https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Server-side_form_validation

My form

```
<form>
    <fieldset name="form_name" addrulepath="components/com_mycomponent/models/rules/myrule.php">
       <field
         name="number" 
         type="text"
         validate="myrule" 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

My `myrule.php` file in `components/com_mycomponent/models/rules/`

```
class JFormRuleMyRule extends JFormRule
{
    protected $regex = '[0-9]';
}
```

Everything is set accordingly and yet it won't work. I may be doing something wrong. Could you please tell me what it is?

The component's name is correct, the file name, class name, path...everything seems to be okay.

If I input letters instead of a number and submit the form, no error is displayed.

My form in the `default.php` file

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_my_component&view=my_view&id='.$this->myItemId['id']); ?>"
    method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" class="form-validate">
       <fieldset name="details">
         <legend>Details</legend>
         <?php echo $this->form->renderFieldset('details');  ?>
       </fieldset>       
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Joomla.submitbutton('send.submit')">Send</button> 

    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
</form>
```

My XML form `myform.xml`

```
    <form name="adminForm" addrulepath="components/com_mycomponent/models/rules">
        <fieldset name="details" 
           <field
             name="day" 
             type="text"
             validate="myrule"
            /> 
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My `myrule.php` file in `components/com_mycomponent/models/rules`

```
class JFormRuleMyRule extends JFormRule
{
    protected $regex = '[0-9]';
}
```

UPDATE:

My controller `send.php` with the `getModel()` overrided

```
class GalleryControllerSend extends JControllerForm
{   
    public function getModel($name = 'Gallery', $prefix = 'GalleryModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true))
    {
        return parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
    }

    public function submit($key = null, $urlVar = null)
    {   

        $this->checkToken();       
        $input=JFactory::getApplication()->input;
        $data  = $input->get('jform', array(), 'array');
        $model = $this->getModel();  // get a handle on your model
        $form = $model->getForm($data, false);  // use the model to build the form  
        $validData = $model->validate($form, $data);  // performs the validation
        $errors = $model->getErrors();  // gets a list of the validation errors 
        $app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i]->getMessage(), 'warning');  // output the error messages   
     }

}
```

gives me `0 - Call to a member function getForm() on bool`

> Call to a member function getForm() on bool
>   [root]\components\com_gallery\controllers\send.php:35

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
addrulepath="components/com_mycomponent/models/rules"
```

and leave out the `/myrule.php`.

I presume you're terminating the `<field  .../>` ok in the XML and adding `<?php` at the start of the rule file?

UPDATE

It looks like your submit button on the form is resulting in task="com_mycomponent.submit" being sent in the HTTP POST request, and is thus running the `submit()` method.

Usually Joomla uses a `Save` button, which sets task="com_xxx.save", which will result in the `save()` method being run.

This method is available in `JControllerForm` and usually covers what you need to do to handle the HTTP POST.

However, it's instructive to get this working by yourself in your submit function, but you have to add some extra lines. The relevant lines from `JControllerForm::save` which you want to incorporate are

```
$data = $this->input->post->get('jform', array(), 'array');  // just change your variable from $form to $data, to follow convention

$model = $this->getModel();  // get a handle on your model

$form = $model->getForm($data, false);  // use the model to build the form

$validData = $model->validate($form, $data);  // performs the validation

$errors = $model->getErrors();  // gets a list of the validation errors

$app->enqueueMessage($errors[$i]->getMessage(), 'warning');  // output the error messages
```

By the way, you might find https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_verifications useful as well.

For your model override try:

```
public function getModel($name = 'Gallery', $prefix = 'GalleryModel', $config = array('ignore_request' => true))
{
    return parent::getModel($name, $prefix, $config);
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you. I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: It's still not working even after the changes. Maybe something to do with my form/submit button in `default.php` file?

Comment: So i either do these modifications or change my button name to `save`?

Comment: Gave me this error `Call to a member function getForm() on bool`

Comment: Looks like the getModel() call isn't returning your model. You'll need to override this getModel() function in your controller to get it to instantiate your own model. If you can't get it working then let me know the class name of your model and the filepath where it's stored. You'd be better to get your submit() function working first, but at the end of the day it's probably worth it to switch to a Save button.

Comment: Yes, actually i have no problem chaging names, however, i think i have tried switching the name of the button to `save` but it didn't work either. Let me override the model.

Comment: I overrided and now it says `Call to a member function getForm() on null`  the class name is `GalleryModelGallery`and filepath is `[ROOT]/components/com_gallery/models/gallery.php`

Comment: OK I've updated my answer with a suggestion for your getModel() function in your controller.

Comment: I have tried what you recomended but i get the same error.

Comment: i actually have these validation rules working in my component, but it's on the admin part, i wanted to add custom rules to the site part too. I have tried figuring out why the admin part works but the site does not.

Comment: I don't know Thiago - I put your code above into a component and it worked ok! I zipped up my component and put it up on my google drive at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TgGtsM6hPLSk-iO3K9W3vM1iMEAd8Wyd/view?usp=sharing so you can download it and have a look and see what the difference is if you like.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time spent trying to help me and you actually helped me a lot! I'm very much appreciated. By the way, an "l" was missing in the prefix haha. I had "GaleryModel" instead of "GalleryModel"

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might have been something trivial like that! Glad to hear you got it sorted. I'll remove that zip file from my google drive.